# ExceptT Dead Code Detection

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

In a `ExceptT` Monad transformer stack, bind expressions after `throwE` will not get executed.

1. Is it true?
2. If so how can I configure the compiler or my tooling to detect dead code like this example?

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE
    GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving
#-}

import Control.Monad.Except (MonadError (..), MonadIO, liftIO)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Except (ExceptT, runExceptT, throwE)

newtype MyTrans e a = MyTrans { unMyTrans :: ExceptT e IO a  } 
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO, MonadError e)

throwMT :: e -> MyTrans e a
throwMT = MyTrans . throwE

runMyTrans :: MyTrans e a -> IO (Either e a)
runMyTrans = runExceptT . unMyTrans

comp = do
  liftIO $ putStrLn "Starting Computation"
  throwMT "Some Error"
  -- dead code from this line
  liftIO $ putStrLn "Ending Computation"
  return ()


main = print =<< runMyTrans comp
```

Comment: They definitely get executed, it's just that they're designed to be a no-op. If you don't want that functionality, don't use that function.

Comment: I don't understand it, from my point of view nothing gets evaluated after `throwE`, for example this `throwMT "Some Error" >>= undefined` does not result in a runtime error.

Comment: The bind will be evaluated, but the function parameter is ignored if there's been an exception. That's part of the definition of `ExceptT`. You could call it dead code, but that behavior is kind of the point of the monad.

Answer (score 3):

1. It is true.
2. I know of no dead-code elimination tools available today for Haskell.

Answer (score 3):

Let's ignore the `MyTrans` newtype noise, and just look at

```
throwE x >>= f :: ExceptT e IO a
```

Digging into `Control.Monad.Trans.Except`, we see

```
newtype ExceptT e m a =
  ExceptT {runExceptT :: m (Either e a)}

throwE :: Monad m => e -> ExceptT e m a
throwE e = ExceptT (pure (Left e))

instance Monad m => Monad (ExceptT e m) where
  m >>= f = ExceptT $ do
    res <- runExceptT m
    case res of
      Left e -> pure (Left e)
      Right r -> runExceptT (f r)
```

Inlining these (something GHC likes to do), we see that `throwE e >>= f` is

```
ExceptT $ do
  res <- pure (Left e)
  case res of
    Left e -> pure (Left e)
    Right r -> runExceptT (f r)
```

Given just this for an arbitrary monad, GHC wouldn't get any further, because it doesn't know that `m` is a law-abiding monad and doesn't look for "free theorems" that could potentially help.

However, this isn't an arbitrary monad! It's `IO`!

```
newtype IO a =
  IO (State# RealWorld
            -> (# State# RealWorld, a #))
unIO :: IO a -> State# RealWorld
            -> (# State# RealWorld, a #)
unIO (IO f) = f

instance Monad IO where
  return a = IO $ \s -> (# s, a #)
  IO m >>= f = IO $ \s ->
    case m s of
      (# s', a #) -> unIO (f a) s'
```

The left identity law can be "proved" for `IO` by optimization.

```
return a >>= g
= inlining
IO $ \s ->
  case (\t -> (# t, a #)) s of
    (# s', r #) -> unIO (g r) s'
= beta reduction
IO $ \s ->
  case (# s, a #) of
    (# s', r #) -> unIO (g r) s'
= case of known constructor
IO $ \s -> unIO (g a) s
= (assuming g has arity at least two, which it will here)
g a
```

Applying this information, `throwE e >>= f` becomes

```
ExceptT $
  (\res -> case res of
    Left e -> pure (Left e)
    Right r -> runExceptT (f r)) (Left e)
```

Beta reducing and applying case of known constructor yields

```
ExceptT $ pure (Left e)
```

The dead code has been completely eliminated.